# Managing conflict in schema.rb created by Git operation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, migration

I created a migration, ran `rake db:migrate`, which bumped my db/schema.rb version number. Then I did a `git fetch origin master` and saw that there were changes from my team members. So I did a `git stash` and a `git rebase FETCH_HEAD`, followed by a `git stash pop`. This resulted in a conflict in db/schema.rb over the version number.

```
Upstream>>>
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20110930179257) do
===========
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20110930161932) do
<<<Stashed
```

I think the appropriate fix would be to manually increment the version number to something higher than the upstream.

Is this sensible, or bad news?

Thanks,
Max

Comment: To answer my own question, manually incrementing the version number is not necessary, and, in all likelihood, a bad idea. All that is needed, from what I can tell, is to just accept the upstream version number.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

If your current database has the correct schema, you should:

- Run pending migrations (if any)

  ```
  rake db:migrate
  ```
- Overwrite your `schema.rb` from your current database schema

  ```
  rake db:schema:dump
  ```
- And commit

Comment: Not sure if this works in my situation. I had pending migrations from upstream.

Comment: If you have pending migrations, run them then `rake db:schema:dump`

Comment: Wouldn't this create a pull request with no change to the version in schema.rb, if the remote's version is higher?

Answer (score 23):

When I find myself with this conflict, I simply migrate the database. Whether there are pending migrations or not, the conflict will be corrected.

Answer (score 20):

## tldr

Accept the Upstream version and run `rake db:migrate` as you'd normally do.

## why is that the way to go

Don't worry about the migrations you've created (which are below Upstream version `20110930179257`). ActiveRecord uses a table `schema_migrations` where it puts all of the migrations that have been run. If your migrations aren't on the list but in `db/migrate` directory, then ActiveRecord will run them.

Here's the table so you can visualise it better:
[image: schema_migrations table]

It's tempting to think that it's actually this line:
`ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20110930179257)`
that defines latest migration run, so no migrations with version below it are going to be run. This is fortunately not true. Rails will run any migrations that are in `db/migrate` folder and not yet in the `schema_migrations` table.

Answer (score 7):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4047884/474597), a conflict is guaranteed. The user has to to manually merge, and set the version as the higher of the two.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I do when merging master into my feature branch fails over conflicts in db/schema.rb:

```
$ git merge --abort
$ git checkout master
$ rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
$ git checkout -- db/schema.rb
$ git checkout my_feature_branch
$ rake db:migrate
$ git add db/schema.rb
$ git commit -m 'Updated schema'
$ git merge master
```

Answer (score 1):

`~/bin/update-schema-rb`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

git co master
bin/rake db:reset db:seed
git co -
bin/rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is to have a manual version script which is additive only. There you want conflicts. Schema is something that will bite you hard if you don't keep on top of it. So once bitten, twice shy, I don't mind keeping schema and lookup info (list of customer types) with an additive only change management scheme.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the best approach is to do `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate` to regenerate schema using migrations that exist only on the current branch. That way migrations from other branches won't leak into your schema file and give you headache later - in case if you switch branches a lot.