# ActiveRecord::Schema.define info :version in schema.rb --> any need to be sequential?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

In the rails db creation script schema.rb, there is this line at the top:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20111127090505) do
```

The docs (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Schema.html) say that the 
info hash param is optional

- What is :version used for?
- Is there any need for this number to be increasing on checkins? I.e., checkin later in the day makes the version number go down...
- If there are migrations with timestamps greater than given, will they be run run simply because they are not in the migration table, yet the class file exists?
- Are migration files run sequentially?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The version is used to determine what migration was run *last*. This will only increase over time. The migration you've run here was *created* (not *run*) on the 27th November, 2011 at 09:05:05AM in UTC time. This is what the number is: a timestamp.

The number will increase every time you run a newly created migration, this is so Rails will know which one has run last and which one to run next. The next migration to be run will be the one with the first one with the greater number than this number.

And yes, migration files are run in the order they are created.

Comment: Suppose 2 coders:

    A creates migration versionId 1
    B creates migration versionId 2
    B submits migration and schema with schema version updated to 2
    A submits migration and schema with schema version updated to 1

Is that situation OK?

Comment: @justingordon: You would probably encounter a conflict in your db/schema.rb file if that happened. If that does happen, just use the larger number

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering about this too from the point of view of branch-based development (with git and github PRs).

As shown below rails *does* cope with the lack of change in the schema version, and will correctly notice that an older migration has not yet been applied.

---

Given the following rebase of a feature branch "`F`":

```
o
| \
|  F  # migration on Feature branch
A     # other migration merged to main first
```

A rebase of the feature branch results in a conflict on `schema.rb` on the version. Resolving it with a `migrate`+`dump` as per [Managing conflict in schema.rb created by Git operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614215/managing-conflict-in-schema-rb-created-by-git-operation/7614339#7614339) :

```sh
$ git checkout main
$ rails db:migrate      # apply new migration from commit A on main branch
$ git checkout feature
$ git rebase main       # stops on conflict
$ rails db:migrate && rails db:schema:dump  # overwrite conflicted schema file
$ git add db/schema.rb  # mark conflict as resolved
$ git rebase --continue
```

```
o
|
|
A     # other migration merged to main first
F'    # rebased B, no longer has diff on schema
```

and then checking the migration status, shows that rails *does* understand that one of the "older" migrations has not been run without relying on the version information in `schema.rb`.

```sh
$ rails db:migrate:status | tail -n 5
   up     20210609094438  Add access booleans to token
  down    20210610090328  Add uplift to early career teacher profile
   up     20210611133458  Change default api token type
   up     20210611141524  Update e and l tokens with private access
```

---

The resultant schema patch, note that there is no diff on the version:

```
diff --git a/db/schema.rb b/db/schema.rb
index 4523b11b..c7bbd6e0 100644
--- a/db/schema.rb
+++ b/db/schema.rb
@@ -153,0 +154 @@ ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_06_11_141524) do
+    t.boolean "uplift", default: false, null: false
```

---

*Tested on `Rails 6.1.3.2`*