# How does a migration from a Git branch get run on Heroku if a later migration from a different branch has already been run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, database-migration

Say I create a branch (`new_branch`). In that branch, a migration (`migration_1`) is created.

Later, I switch back to `master`. I then create a migration (`migration_2`), push to Heroku, and run migrations on Heroku.

Later still, I merge `new_branch` into `master`, and then push `master` to Heroku.

When I try to run migrations on Heroku, won't `migration_1` be skipped over and not run, because it was created before `migration_2`, which has already been run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each migration has a migration timestamp attached. The list of successfully applied migrations is stored in a schema table inside your Rails application.

When you run `migration_2`, this entry is added to the database. When `migration_1` is merged, Rails will detect the change has not been applied yet because the entry is missing in the schema table, and will run it.

Comment: So I already marked this as the answer, but I have a question. How is this answer compatible with the ones in [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979059/is-the-version-number-in-rails-schema-rb-used-for-anything)? There, the consensus is that it is assumed that all migrations prior to the schema version number have already been run.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#what-s-in-a-name seems to agree with Simone's answer.