# Rails Migration Order and Git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, migration, rails-migrations

Since doing migrations with rails + git is type of a pain, a new thorn has sprung..

Before I am doing any harm to my prod DB, would the following situation cause havoc? If so, how would I handle it?

I am working a long-term feature in a separate branch (`feature/long-term`). This feature is an overhaul of a lot of components and it will take awhile to complete. This feature has new migrations, which were migrated to the localhost DB.

meanwhile, I need to fix/add a migration to the prod system via another branch (`feature/quick-fix`). This has a migration file with date later than the `feature/long-term` migration.

The migrations of the `quick-fix` and the `long-term` have nothing to do with each other, they do not collide and work on separate tables. It doesn't matter what order they are run.

If I merge `feature/quick-fix` to master and `db:migrate` and in a few days/weeks merge `feature/long-term` the migration files order would be the `long-term` first.

Would this affect the DB in some way? (the prod DB is important, so I don't want to `reset`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you described is a very common development workflow (especially so in teams with more members) and it's perfectly safe for your production DB.

Rails, as of version 2.1, is smart enough to keep a list of all migrations ever run, instead of just the latest migration version run. This information is stored on a separate table aptly named `schema_migrations`.

So, if you push a new migration today, say `20140527_quick_fix.rb`, and a month after that you push a new (but with an older timestamp) one `20140101_long_term_feature.rb`, Rails will still know that the latter was never run in your production environment so during `rake db:migrate` it will process it, as you would expect. The newest won't be run again of course as the Rails would know that it has already been processed.

From the [official documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html):

> Rails versions 2.0 and prior used to create a table called schema_info when using migrations. This table contained the version of the schema as of the last applied migration.
>
> Starting with Rails 2.1, the schema_info table is (automatically) replaced by the schema_migrations table, which contains the version numbers of all the migrations applied.
>
> As a result, it is now possible to add migration files that are numbered lower than the current schema version: when migrating up, those never-applied “interleaved” migrations will be automatically applied, and when migrating down, never-applied “interleaved” migrations will be skipped.

Comment: When merging the `schema.rb` file, does it matter then what the version number is? Should it be the newer timestamp (but older push), or older timestamp (but newer push)?

Comment: Set the number to the highest one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979059/is-the-version-number-in-rails-schema-rb-used-for-anything/4047884#4047884